# c# Report viewer font stretched when printing

Tags: c#, printing, fonts, reportviewer

We are using Report Viewer in a Windows Form application. The report appears OK when viewing it, but when printing the report or clicking the print layout, the font seems to stretch width-wise and the report spills over into another page.

We've tried setting the cell padding to 0, this helps a bit but the font is still deformed and spills over to the next page.

It works okay when saving to Word, but not to PDF.

Is there a way to keep the same font as the viewer or a way to edit the code behind the print and print layout buttons? There may be a way to set the font or other settings there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to set Report Page size, then Report controls property/font size etc and finally you need to take care while printing.